# Format HTML for Kindle so that chapters appear

Tags: epub, kindle

I'm using an HTML file as my basis for an eBook, that I want to send to my Kindle via Amazon's conversions service. It's working fine, but I can't figure out how to create chapters that work with the 5-way stick. How do you do this?

I tried doing this, but it doesn't work:

```
<mbp:section class="page-header" style="page-break-after: always;" class="chapter">
```

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [breadcrumb titlebar in Kindle book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988699/breadcrumb-titlebar-in-kindle-book) with my (recently updated) answer.

See also this: [Kindle periodical format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379565/kindle-periodical-format)

The problem is related to the MOBI header's `mobi-type` metadata.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Zsolt has wrong. It is not about MOBI-header.
You need to build a NCX file, if you want the navigation in Kindle with 5-way stick. You can find a very detailed related information with examples here:
http://www.cjs-easy-as-pie.com/p/create-ncx-file-by-araby-greene.html

After reading this tutorial, you could build your correct Kindle-book for Amazon Publication.
Good luck!